# How to extract the non-translation part of an Eigen::Affine3d transformation?

Tags: eigen, eigen3

Given an `Eigen::Affine3d` transformation, how do you efficiently extract an `Eigen::Matrix3d` composed of the upper left 3×3 corner of the affine 4×4 matrix?

Currently I use the following non-elegant (but working) syntax:

```
Eigen::Affine3d m_world;
:
Eigen::Matrix3d normMatrix;
normMatrix.col(0) = Vec3(m_world(0,0),m_world(1,0),m_world(2,0));
normMatrix.col(1) = Vec3(m_world(0,1),m_world(1,1),m_world(2,1));
normMatrix.col(2) = Vec3(m_world(0,2),m_world(1,2),m_world(2,2));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Eigen::Transform<>::linear()` method for that purpose:

```
normMatrix = m_world.linear();
```

which is a shortcut for the `MatrixBase::topLeftCorner()` method:

```
normMatrix = m_world.matrix().topLeftCorner<3,3>();
```